# Are functions like $\frac{2\cos(x-\frac{1}{x})}{x^2+2}$ integrable in any way?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, continuity

Is there a way to integrate $$\frac{2\cos(x-\frac{1}{x})}{x^2+2},$$ perhaps through methods other than Riemann integration? I was trying to use Glasser's master theorem to integrate $$\frac{\cos(x)}{x^4+1},$$ but when I graph the former function (after substitution this is the function), it does not look possible. Glasser's master theorem states that both functions must be integrable for the substitution to occur, so I wonder if it is possible .

Comment: Glasser's master theorem applies to principal value integral over the whole real line. Is that what you are interested in?

Comment: @Fabian yes that's what I'm looking for

Comment: I didn't know this theorem before. But Wikipedia says that "It is applicable in cases where the integrals must be construed as Cauchy principal values, and a fortiori it is applicable when the integral converges absolutely." But we clearly have $\int |2\cos (x -x^{-1})/(2+x^2)|dx \leq 2\int 1/(2+x^2)dx <\infty$, so the theorem is applicable. This does not tell you, however, how you compute $\int \cos(x)/(1+x^4)dx$.

Comment: Glasser's Master Theorem can certainly be applied to the numerator, in the current form you can not apply it to the denominator and thus the full integrand. Not to say it can't be done with some rearranging though.

Comment: How did you go from $\cos(x)/(x^4 + 1)$ to $2\cos(x - 1/x)/(x^2 + 2)$ ??